Who is the person on the statue and walls in the beginning of the game in the Scottish Highlands?
I just started playing Hogwarts Legacy and I'm at the beginning of the game in the Scottish Highlands and I'm seeing a person on the wall and on the statue.
I assume it's the same person in all the places. Who is this person? Why is he on the wall and on the statue?



Neither myself nor Professor Fig knows who it is. I assume we might learn later in the game who it is, but I'd like to know now . The more details, the better . I love lore.
I tried searching on Bing and asking Microsoft Copilot:

But Bing didn't give any useful results and Microsoft Copilot's answer was obviously wrong as it suggested that the person on the statue is Professor Fig which obviously isn't true as he's next to me and he doesn't know who the person on the statue is either.

That's Percival Rackham:

Professor Percival Rackham (fl. 1470s) was a Scottish wizard that worked as a Divination professor at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry in the Tudor period, and was the leader of the Keepers.

Those ruins are known as Ruins of Percival Rackham's house, as you can see the statue depicted in the guide is the same.

Are there any statues of him within Hogwarts? (I saw some statues within Hogwarts earlier that also kind of looks like him)

@ShaunRoselt sorry, I have no answer for this :)
